# location (lat long) using facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Is there a way to get the location of a user in  (latitude and longitude format) using facebook api??
I am able to get the location name and other attributes but not the lat long of the place. Is there any API for the same in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the user's basic info, one of the fields is location

```
   "location": {
     "id": "104146386288393", 
     "name": "Newton, Massachusetts"
   },
```

You can make another query using the id of the location to return JSON containing lat/lon of the city, e.g.

```
{
  "id": "104146386288393", 
  "name": "Newton, Massachusetts", 
  "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDygUYzFOcjhDoD&w=100&h=300&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fupload.wikimedia.org\u00252Fwikipedia\u00252Fen\u00252Fe\u00252Fe6\u00252FNewton_City_Hall\u0025252C_Massachusetts.jpg&fallback=hub_city&prefix=s", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Newton-Massachusetts/104146386288393", 
  "likes": 3741, 
  "category": "City", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "is_community_page": true, 
  "description": "<snipped data>", 
  "location": {
    "latitude": 42.3369, 
    "longitude": -71.2097
  }, 
  "checkins": 310, 
  "talking_about_count": 8912
}
```

But of course that's only "close" -- you would need to request the user's address, I guess to get closer.

Comment: I wanted to do a query to get all of a person's friends geographical locations. That would mean doing one query per friend, ouch. that's not a good solution.

Comment: What i've done is made a database that can map the name of the city, state with lat long. but how does this represent non-USA?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/18043993/197184 that does all of the friends at once ;)