# Get latitude/longitude of friend's current_location using Graph FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the latitude/longitude of all of a user's friends using a single API call. I believe I need to write a multi-query FQL statement, but I can't get the syntax correct.

I believe the two queries need to be something like the following:

```
'"friends":"SELECT uid,current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"'

'"location":"SELECT location FROM page WHERE id IN (SELECT current_location_id FROM #friends)"';
```

My problem is that somehow I need to get the ID of the current_location in the first query so that I can reference it in the second query, but I only know how to get an array that contains the id.

Thanks for any help!

**Clarification:**

I'm not trying to get check-ins of friends.  Instead I want to graph the "current_location" (i.e. where they live) of all of a user's friends on a Geo map.  I can get a user's "current_location" with the following FQL query:

```
"SELECT uid,sex,current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
```

This query returns the following array:

```
[current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => New York
                [state] => New York
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 108424279189115
                [name] => New York, New York
            )
```

Which does not contain the longitude and latitude of the of the current_location (New York in the above example)

Therefore I now need to take the ID of the current_location (e.g. 108424279189115) and run a second FQL query such as:

```
"SELECT location,name FROM page WHERE page_id = 108424279189115)"
```

To get the latitude and longitude of the current_location.  Currently, I have a working code that runs the first FQL query, then extracts page_id in php, and then runs a second FQL query to get the current_location latitude/longitude.  However, for performance reasons I would like to run only one multi-query if this is possible.

Comment: I actually never got the array.value syntax to work for me and I just took the performance hit of running to separate FQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

The query should work by adjusting the second query to:

```
'"location":"SELECT location FROM page WHERE id IN (SELECT current_location.id FROM #friends)"';
```

When working with an array type in the FB API you can access the value in any query by doing array.value

Also, if all you need is the page's id, you'll probably get better performance by doing current_location.id in your first query

---

You're going to want to use a fql.multiquery, there is a similair answer here that can be tailored to your needs: [Facebook Graph API get all users and their status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479819/facebook-graph-api-get-all-users-and-their-status)

The FQL documentation on multiquery is located here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Also are you trying to get the lat/long of a checkin object? If so you need to take a look at this resource: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/

Edit:

I'm not sure that what you are trying to do is possible. I just looked through the api and tested some queries, the only way you could get the lat/long from a friend seems to be based on a checkin, from there you can get details on the page if necessary... Even looking at your second query, current_location_id is not referenced anywhere in the page table, and selecting location from the page table is going to give you location info on the place that it pertains to. Maybe you could elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish.

Here is a multiquery statement I wrote in PHP using FQL (it will select the coordinates of all your friends check ins, then from there get details on the place of the checkin pertaining to that friend):

```
try{
    $multiQuery = "{
        'query1':'SELECT coords, tagged_uids, page_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())',
        'query2':'SELECT name, description FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query1)'
    }";

    $param = array(       
         'method' => 'fql.multiquery',       
         'queries' => $multiQuery,       
         'callback' => ''
    );       
    $queryresults = $facebook->api($param);
        print_r($queryresults);
    }
catch(Exception $o){
    print_r($o);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but unless I'm missing something it doesn't answer my question. I understand the example you posted (getting user statuses), but in this case they simply get the UID of all their friends and then use the UID to query their status. However, my problem is that I don't know how to query the ID of the current_location.  I can get all my friend's current_location as in query #friends I wrote above, but this returns an object.  And I can't use an object to do another query. How do I get the id instead of the object. Should be simple but I can't find any examples

Comment: To clarify, when I say the query returns an "object" for current_location I mean the query returns and "array".

Comment: Have you checked to see what is contained in the array object? Can you run a print_r($object); and paste the results, if any? I will give the code a try later today or tomorrow morning if you still cannot figure it out

Comment: The current_location array certainly contains the place ID. And I can then extract the ID using PHP and run a second query such as: "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM place WHERE page_id = 106300959405546" to get the desired data.  However, instead of extracting the IDs in php and then running the second query, I'd like to run a single query (likely a multi-query) for performance reasons. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The current_location array contains the following data:

    [current_location] => Array
                (
                    [city] => Minneapolis
                    [state] => Minnesota
                    [country] => United States
                    [zip] => 
                    [id] => 106300959405546
                    [name] => Minneapolis, Minnesota
                )

Comment: please review my edits... as I said I may need more elaboration on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. Please see my clarification of the original question.

Comment: alright i gotcha man, I prolly had too many beers last time I looked at this. I think all you need to do is adjust your second query like so (to get the id out of the current_location array): '"location":"SELECT location FROM page WHERE id IN (SELECT current_location.id FROM #friends)"';

Comment: it seems that when working with an array type in the API you can always access one of the values by doing array.value - give it a shot let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. The "array.value" syntax doesn't seem to be working for me.  When I add ".id" to my "current_location" in my working FQL query, I don't get any response at all.  I'm using www.webtechnick.com cakephp plugin, I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.  I'm running out of time so I've decided to table this issue for now and take the hit in performance. Thanks again though. BTW, where did you find "array.value" syntax documented?

Comment: Ive used the array.value before albeit in 2.0 php fql, although i cant imagine it has changed, ill plug the query in behind the scenes behind my dev app to make sure it runs properly but i suspect it should work, ill post my findings in the next day

Answer (score 2):

```
fql?q=SELECT location,name FROM page WHERE page_id in (SELECT current_location.id from user where uid in(select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()))
```

this will do the magic for you

Answer (score 1):

```
facebook.batch_fql({
    'query1': "SELECT uid, name, current_location.id FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())",
    'query2': "SELECT page_id, name, description, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT current_location.id FROM #query1)"
})
```

will return two responses

one will be a list of friends UIDs, names and their current locations IDs

the other will be a list of unique location IDs with their name, description and geolocation info

**EDIT**: if you query for current_location using FQL, you'll get the full latlong in the first response and you don't even need the second one