# facebook api how to get lat/long from user_location

Tags: php, facebook, api, location

There is a discussion here:  [location (lat long) using facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427702/location-lat-long-using-facebook-api)  but it doesn't show how to get it...

I can get the basic info:

```
"location": {
 "id": "104146386288393", 
 "name": "Newton, Massachusetts"
   },
```

but how to I make a request using the location ID to get

```
{
  "id": "104146386288393", 
  "name": "Newton, Massachusetts", 
  "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDygUYzFOcjhDoD&w=100&h=300&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fupload.wikimedia.org\u00252Fwikipedia\u00252Fen\u00252Fe\u00252Fe6\u00252FNewton_City_Hall\u0025252C_Massachusetts.jpg&fallback=hub_city&prefix=s", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Newton-Massachusetts/104146386288393", 
  "likes": 3741, 
  "category": "City", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "is_community_page": true, 
  "description": "<snipped data>", 
  "location": {
    "latitude": 42.3369, 
    "longitude": -71.2097
  }, 
  "checkins": 310, 
  "talking_about_count": 8912
}
```

Here is my code for facebook:

```
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id, first_name, location'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

- Authorize the user with `user_location`
- Make a GET request to `/me?fields=location`
- Make a GET request to the location id you get in the result of `/me`

...meaning, you just need to do an extra API call to get latitude/longitude.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get my location ID from my array... if I use `$_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["location"]["id"]` it doesn't work ... any idea how to get my location ID from the array?

Comment: not sure how you are trying to achieve this. why session? why fb_user_details? just make an api call to /me and it will be in the returned result.

Comment: Just an update, it won't be returned in the default /me result. You have now to do /me?fields=location. Additionally, location is now also referring to a Page with id at location.id. That Page then has a location field which is of the Location type, which has coords, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with [the graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&) tool before implementation.

After having location id, you need to call "location_id"?fields=location to get long/lat

[image]